# Fluentd S3 output plugin not recognizing index

Tags: amazon-web-services, fluentd

I am facing problems while using S3 output plugin with fluent-d.

```
 s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}
```

using %index at end never resolves to _0,_1 . But i always end up with log file names as

sflow_.log

while i need sflow_0.log

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your fluent.conf?. It's hard to find the problem without full info. File creations are mainly controlled by time slice flag and buffer configuration..

```
<buffer>
    @type file or memory
    path /fluentd/buffer/s3
    timekey_wait 1m
    timekey 1m
    chunk_limit_size 64m
</buffer>
time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M
```

With above, you create a file every minute and within 1min if your buffer limit is reached or due to any other factor another file is created with index 1 under same minute.